# broken anaconda after windows update

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spyder, anaconda3

My PC with windows 10 updated last night and to my surprise this morning Anaconda stopped working. I've already deleted and made a clean reinstall of anaconda and still fails to lunch.
By opening an anaconda prompt i get the following.
[image]

Can't manage to see where the problem might be. Tried installing collections with pip to see weather that was the issue but did not work. If i try use the conda command it just returns that is not a recognized command

Comment: Copy the configuration of all your environments (see anaconda docs on cloning environments). Move/rename conda, and reinstall it. (and if all is ok, just remove the old conda, if you have problems you can move back old conda): there is some file which is outdated maybe a pyc, or dll, and new conda is using the old file and not the new one.